# Mercurial SCM - What does 'hg' stand for?

Tags: mercurial

Git uses `git status`, Mercurial uses `hg status`.

What does the `hg` stand for? I have thoroughly searched for it, to no avail.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`Hg` is the chemical symbol for Mercury, element # 80 in the periodic table:

[image]

The symbol comes from `Hydragyrum`, the name for the substance using Greek roots, meaning (roughly) "silver water" (another name for Mercury was quicksilver).

Comment: Ha! I see - so obvious now.

Answer (score 1):

The element [Mercury](http://webelements.com/mercury/) has the symbol Hg.